# Create a new github repository from github template for organization using API is possible or not?

Tags: git, github, github-api

I am trying to create an API for all the git actions. I am able to do most of the things but not able to create a new repository inside my organization using a template.

I tried this endpoint : [https://api.github.com/repos/{template_org_name}/{template_repo}/generate](https://api.github.com/repos/%7Btemplate_org_name%7D/%7Btemplate_repo%7D/generate)

Is there any other endpoint for doing this? Your help is highly appreciated!